# How to use delete() query in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset, django-orm

I am trying to delete one of the items of a field in the table.
For example, I want to remove the 'hadi', shown in the image, from the table.
I make a query to filter and exclude instance but in the final part, `delete()` query does not accept input such as id or variable to remove the specific thing in one field.

[image]

**models.py**

```
class Expense(models.Model):
    expenser = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    debtors = models.ManyToManyField(
        CustomUser,
        related_name='debtors',     
    )

    amount = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    text = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateField(null=True)
    time = models.TimeField(null=True)

    def get_debtors(self):
        return ", ".join([str(d) for d in self.debtors.all()])

    def who_has_no_paid(self):
        return ", ".join([str(d) for d in self.debtors.all() if str(d) != str(self.expenser)])

    def debt(self):
        return int(float(self.amount/self.debtors.all().count()))

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('expense_detail', args=[self.id])
```

Now, what is the query that should be used in view?

Comment: use remove() instead of delete(). https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.remove

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a many to many field you need to use expense_obj.debtors.remove(hadi_obj) rather than using delete().

[Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) is really good for referencing

your view could be :

```py
def remove_hadi(request):
   expense_obj = Expense.objects.get(id=some_id) #get the expense obj from where u want to remove hadi
   hadi_obj = User.objects.get(name="hadi") # get user obj u want to remove eg: hadi
   # use m2m query
   expense_obj.debtors.remove(hadi_obj)
   return response
```